# Google Info Window Issue with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I seem to have a situation here that could be quite a common question. I am creating a google map marker on a right click. This marker contains an input form for users. This all works fine. However, as part of that form, there is a filter function. On clicking any item in the list, I am trying to display the item as part of the value span directly below this list, however, this is not working.

Is there some kind of block to using this methodology in an info window or as part of a variable? Am I just being thick?

(I have included the filter function together with the event listener portion of my code relating to the marker)

**Filter function:**

```
<script>
function iwproductFilter() {
// Declare variables
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
input = document.getElementById('userInput');
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

// Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
}
</script>
```

**Event Listener**

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        //Right Click to Drop a New Marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {
            //Edit form to be displayed with new marker
            var EditForm = '<p><div class="marker-edit">'+
            '<form method="POST" name="SaveMarker" id="SaveMarker">'+
            '<label for="pType"><span>Product:</span>'+'<input type="text" id="userInput" onkeyup="iwproductFilter()" placeholder="Search for names..">'+'&nbsp;'+'&nbsp;'+'&nbsp;'+
            '<a onclick="document.getElementById(\'userInput\').value = \'\'; iwproductFilter();" style="font-size:16px;cursor:pointer;"</a>'+'&#10006'+
            '<ul id="myUL">'+
            '<li id="1a"><a>Adele</a></li>'+
            '<li id="1b"><a>Agnes</a></li>'+
            '<li id="1c"><a>Billy</a></li>'+
            '<li id="1d"><a>Bob</a></li>'+
            '<li id="1e"><a>Calvin</a></li>'+
            '<li id="1f"><a>Christina</a></li>'+
            '<li id="1g"><a>Cindy</a></li>'+
            '<li id="1h"><a>Doug</a></li>'+
            '</ul>'+
            '<span>Value:</span><span style="font-weight:bold;color:red"><a id="prodResult" name="pType" class="save-type">Select Product :)</a></span>'+
            '<scr'+'ipt>'+
            'var prod1a = document.getElementById("1a");'+
            'var prod1b = document.getElementById("1b");'+
            'var prod1c = document.getElementById("1c");'+
            'var prod1d = document.getElementById("1d");'+
            'var prod1e = document.getElementById("1e");'+
            'var prod1f = document.getElementById("1f");'+
            'var prod1g = document.getElementById("1g");'+
            'var prod1h = document.getElementById("1h");'+
            'var y = document.getElementById("prodResult");'+
            'y.innerHTML = "Select Product:)";'+
            'prod1a.onclick = function() {y.innerHTML = "Adele";}'+
            'prod1b.onclick = function() {y.innerHTML = "Agnes";}'+
            'prod1c.onclick = function() {y.innerHTML = "Billy";}'+
            'prod1d.onclick = function() {y.innerHTML = "Bob";}'+
            'prod1e.onclick = function() {y.innerHTML = "Calvin";}'+
            'prod1f.onclick = function() {y.innerHTML = "Cindy";}'+
            'prod1g.onclick = function() {y.innerHTML = "Doug";}'+
            'prod1h.onclick = function() {y.innerHTML = "Erika";}'+
            'prod1i.onclick = function() {y.innerHTML = "Fred";}'+
            'prod1j.onclick = function() {y.innerHTML = "Gareth";}'+
            'prod1l.onclick = function() {y.innerHTML = "Harvy";}'+
            '</scr'+'ipt>'+
            '<select name="pType" class="save-type"><option value="restaurant">Rastaurant</option><option value="bar">Bar</option>'+
            '<option value="house">House</option></select></label>'+
            '<label for="pUserName"><span>Place Name :</span><input type="text" name="pUserName" class="save-name" placeholder="Enter Title" maxlength="40" /></label>'+
            '<label for="pDesc"><span>Notes:</span><textarea name="pDesc" class="save-desc" placeholder="Max 50 Characters" maxlength="50"></textarea></label>'+
            '</form>'+
            '</div></p><button name="save-marker" class="save-marker">Add Product</button>';


</script>
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You question is missing the code that adds a marker to the map and an info window to that marker. Could you include that? Also, is EditForm meant to be the content of the info window?

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple example in [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/noyige/5/edit?js,output) and used the following code to achieve the functionality you are looking for:

```
var myList = document.getElementById('myUL');

myList.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    var name = event.target.textContent;
    var result = document.getElementById('prodResult');
    result.textContent = name;
  }
});
```

The above code will only work if the info window is displayed on the map; that is: if its contents have been added to the DOM. So in order to ensure that this is the case, I only run the code when the info window's `domready` event is fired.

```
infoWindow.addListener('domready', addListClickListener);
```

According to the [Google Map Docs on Info Windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/info-window), `domready`

> is fired when the  containing the InfoWindow's content is attached to the DOM.

Comment: @Nick1991 did you give this a try?